# login validation javascript not working right

Tags: javascript, jsp, validation, ajaxform

So I have this log in form that checks if the user exists in database and if the password and the username match. If something is wrong an error message appears but despite that the user can submit his answers even if they are wrong! How can I block the submit button until the answers are correct?

```html
<form
  id="login"
  action="loginController1.jsp"
  onsubmit="return validateLogin()"
>
  <input
    id="username"
    name="username"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Username"
    autofocus
    onkeyup="validateUsername()"
    required
  />
  <span id="loginstatus"> </span>
  <input
    id="password"
    name="password"
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    onkeyup="validateLogin()"
    required
  />
  <span id="loginstatus1"> </span>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateUsername() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var urls = "checkLogin.jsp?uname=" + u;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        document.getElementById("loginstatus").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateLogin() {
    var xmlhttp;
    var u = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var p = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var urls = "checkLogin1.jsp?uname=" + u + "&pwd=" + p;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // code for IE6, IE5

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4)
        document.getElementById("loginstatus1").innerHTML =
          xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", urls, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You don't reutnr `false` from validateLogin when logging in failed.

Comment: Make sure you encrypt your username and password before sending them in a query string.

Comment: I doestn't work with return false either

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the button by default:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in" disabled="true">
```

Then in validateLogin add a line to enable the button:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
        document.getElementById("loginstatus1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    else
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
}
```

You would probably also want to add this line to the top of each validation function:

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
```

Otherwise it would be possible for the user to follow this sequence:

1. user enters a valid username and password
2. your code verifies the entries and enables the login button
3. user changes the login name or password to something invalid
4. user clicks the submit button